# Button in a form, to append that chunk of form to overall form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Button in a form, to append that chunk of form to overall form using javascript.

What am I doing wrong in this line of code in my `html.erb` file?

```
<%= button_to "Add Another Record", '$('.records-container').append('<%=j render partial: 'records/form'%>');'%>
```

Comment: Hi, a quick question. Do you want to append multiple nested form in a form?

Comment: I have a Person model with has_many records model. I want to be able to create multiple records while creating a person. I have record nested in person working. Just was trying to get a button in person form to add more form for records as needed. I have my record form in a partial trying to render it in js.erb file so that I can keep rendering it. I'm new at this(obviously) help please. I still struggle with syntax. Those quotes get me. :)

Answer (score 1):

[button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) does not do what you think it does :)

If you really want to use inline javascript, you could do something like

```
link_to 'Add another record', '#', onclick: "$(..).append(..); return false;"
```

But truthfully: that style of javascript programming we try to avoid. So alternative approach:

```
link_to 'Add another record', '#', 
   'data-template' => CGI.escapeHTML(render('records/form').to_str).html_safe
```

and in your javascript add something like:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-template]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this     = $(this),
      content   = $this.data('template');
  $('.records-container').append(content);
)
```

This is simple version (untested) of the code used in cocoon, a gem to build nested forms.
If you are trying to build nested forms however, I would suggest to check out [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/) (because in that case you would also need to, at least, create unique id's for each new nested form)

Comment: I didn't use a gem for my nested form I did accepts_nested_attributes method.  Can i still use your approach with that method? I initially was trying to do a button to & it render the new.js.erb which was rendering that bit of javascript.  Help/thoughts?

Comment: `button_to` would not work because it is intended to build a form to allow to POST data without having to explicitly build the form. Check the docs I linked to. You would need to do a simple `link_to`, with an explicit `onclick` as mentioned in my answer, and yes it should work. However when adding multiple nested forms this way, as mentioned, it will no longer work. You could also render a new form using ajax. But if you are using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, it seems wise to just use the cocoon gem as it is easier imho. Just check the documentation and see if it fits your problem.